# PostgreSQL Select the r.* by MIN() with group-by on two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

### The example schema of a table called `results`

| id | user_id | activity_id | activity_type_id | start_date_local | elapsed_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 11111 | 1 | 2014-01-07 04:34:38 | 4444 |
| 2 | 100 | 22222 | 1 | 2015-04-14 06:44:42 | 5555 |
| 3 | 100 | 33333 | 1 | 2015-04-14 06:44:42 | 7777 |
| 4 | 100 | 44444 | 2 | 2014-01-07 04:34:38 | 12345 |
| 5 | 200 | 55555 | 1 | 2015-12-22 16:32:56 | 5023 |

### The problem

Select the results of fastest activities (i.e. minimum elapsed time) of each user by `activity_type_id` and `year`.

(Basically, in this simplified example, record ID=3 should be excluded from the selection, because record ID=2 is the fastest for user 100 of the given activity_type_id 1 and the year of 2015)

### What I have tried

```
SELECT user_id,
       activity_type_id,
       EXTRACT(year FROM start_date_local) AS year,
       MIN(elapsed_time) AS fastest_time
FROM results
GROUP BY activity_type_id, user_id, year
ORDER BY activity_type_id, user_id, year;
```

#### Actual

Which selects the correct result set I want, but only contains the grouped by columns

| user_id | activity_type_id | year | fastest_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 2014 | 4444 |
| 100 | 1 | 2015 | 5555 |
| 100 | 2 | 2014 | 12345 |
| 200 | 1 | 2015 | 5023 |

#### Goal

To have the actual full record with all columns. i.e. `results.*` + `year`

| id | user_id | activity_id | activity_type_id | start_date_local | year | elapsed_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 11111 | 1 | 2014-01-07 04:34:38 | 2014 | 2014 |
| 2 | 100 | 22222 | 1 | 2015-04-14 06:44:42 | 2015 | 5555 |
| 4 | 100 | 44444 | 2 | 2014-01-07 04:34:38 | 2014 | 12345 |
| 5 | 200 | 55555 | 1 | 2015-12-22 16:32:56 | 2015 | 5023 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, activity_type_id, EXTRACT(year FROM start_date_local)) 
     *, EXTRACT(year FROM start_date_local) AS year
FROM results
ORDER BY user_id, activity_type_id, year, elapsed_time;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function for this:

```
select id, user_id, activity_id, activity_type_id, start_date_local, year, elapsed_time
from (
  SELECT id, 
         user_id,
         activity_id,
         activity_type_id,
         start_date_local,
         EXTRACT(year FROM start_date_local) AS year,
         elapsed_time,
         min(elapsed_time) over (partition by user_id, activity_type_id, EXTRACT(year FROM start_date_local)) as fastest_time
  FROM results
) t
where elapsed_time = fastest_time
order by activity_type_id, user_id, year;
```

Alternatively using `distinct on ()`

```
select distinct on (activity_type_id, user_id, extract(year from start_date_local)) 
       id, 
       user_id,
       activity_id,
       activity_type_id,
       extract(year from start_date_local) as year,
       elapsed_time
from results
order by activity_type_id, user_id, year, elapsed_time;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bb9b7bf14c8c04802505033067b37b56)